# Hibernate - update an object (entity) in DB, based on "not complete" object, without loosing values, for already filled columns

Tags: java, sql, database, spring, hibernate

I wanted to update object in Hibernate, which let say has 3 fields, already filled in (**id=1, firstname="kim", lastname="kardashian"**), based on some "delta" object (**id=1, firstname="kimirsen", lastname=*null***).

I'm using:

```
Session.update(object);
```

and my Object entity class has below annotation:

```
@DynamicUpdate
```

that I've found it's required.

However I'm still getting:

```
NULL not allowed for column "LASTNAME"; SQL statement:
```

exception.

Is there any way, to update object, without checking each and every fields (if it's null, if yes, then query field in DB to check, if it's already filled in or not...)?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to update only the firstname, then you should query the DB and get the object with id, and modify the firstname, before calling the update.

I don't think you can leave out lastname, and expect Hibernate to ignore it.

DynamicUpdate is for specifying whether Hibernate should update in the DB, all the fields of the Persitent Object or only the modified fields (in comparison to the db).

Comment: Ok, but if I would have multiple fields (not as in example), then I have to write some big logic, to handle this.
I tougth, it's possbile somehow, to tell Hibernate, to update object, but ommit "empty" fields - leave them, as exist in DB as for now.